# flutter_native_splash package created image in center of screen in both ios and android

Tags: flutter

i used **flutter_native_splash** package for created splash screen
but image in center of screen in both **IOS** and **Android**
my **Pubspec.yaml**

```
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19

  flutter_native_splash:
    color: "#ffffff"
    image: assets/images/splash_screen.jpeg
    android: true
    ios: true
    fullscreen: true
```

i tried many ways but the best was doing it native android and ios

Comment: image was in center of the splash screen, searched but with no result, i solved it with native. so i posted question with answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have solved it my add native configuration in ios and android

in **android**

go to

1- android\app\src\main\res\drawable-v21

2- android\app\src\main\res\drawable

and change gravity to fill not center

[image]

in **ios**

1-open ios folder with xcode

2-go to runner and launch screen

3-change content mode to "scale to fill" not center

[image]